# Apache poi XWPF Paragraph line spacing

Tags: java, apache, coldfusion, apache-poi

I am looking at trying to build a word document using Apache Poi in Java/Coldfusion.   So far it's letting me do a lot of the formatting I want except for line spacing of a paragraph.  Does anyone know how I would set a paragraph to be single line spaced?  It keeps building documents that have Multiple spaced paragraphs, with 1.15 as the spacing.

Here's an example of the code:

```
document = loader.create("org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument");
ParagraphAlignment = loader.create("org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment" );
paragraphOne = document.createParagraph();
paragraphOne.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

paragraphOneRunOne = paragraphVar.createRun();
paragraphOneRunOne.setFontFamily('Cambria');
paragraphOneRunOne.setFontSize(12);
paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(false);
paragraphOneRunOne.setText(Here's one line of text in this paragraph);
paragraphOneRunOne.addBreak();

paragraphOneRunTwo = paragraphVar.createRun();
paragraphOneRunTwo.setFontFamily('Cambria');
paragraphOneRunTwo.setFontSize(12);
paragraphOneRunTwo.setBold(false);
paragraphOneRunTwo.setText(Here's a second line of text in this paragraph);
paragraphOneRunTwo.addBreak();
```

I've looked through examples and the api docs, and the only settings I can find for line spacing determine the line spacing before or after a paragraph, not within the paragraph for linespacing of the text.

Anyone encounter this before or have any exmaples of how to fix it?

Comment: From a quick look at the API, did you try [`setSpacingLineRule(..)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setSpacingLineRule%28org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.LineSpacingRule%29)?

Comment: I looked into that, but the API was unclear on how to use that to dictate single vs double vs multi spacing in the document.  It seemed to be an enumerator that only has 3 values EXACT, AUTO and AT_LEAST.

Comment: Those are based on the [options provided in MS Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/adjust-the-line-spacing-between-text-or-paragraphs-HP010016523.aspx#BM2) `Single, Double, At least, Exactly, Multiple, ...` It looks like POI only supports a subset of those.

Comment: That is roughly what I was afraid of and I can't find any other documentation on how to create a style to apply to the paragraph that would do the same thing

Comment: So, not technically a fix, just a workaround.  I found I could knock it back to single line spacing if I created a blank word doc, set paragraph line spacing, save it and use that as my starting point for a WXPFDocument.

Technically, not a great fix, because you can't switch back and forth if needed, but for my purposes it will probably work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and found a solution after going through the ooxml-schemas source and the internals of the docx file generated. Here is the code

```
public void setSingleLineSpacing(XWPFParagraph para) {
    CTPPr ppr = para.getCTP().getPPr();
    if (ppr == null) ppr = para.getCTP().addNewPPr();
    CTSpacing spacing = ppr.isSetSpacing()? ppr.getSpacing() : ppr.addNewSpacing();
    spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.AUTO);
    spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(240));
}
```

Comment: How would I fit that in this?:
InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File("..\\entradas\\cartas\\87109.docx"));
   XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
   PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("..\\entradas\\cartas\\87109docx.pdf"));
   PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
   System.out.println("Done");

Answer (score 1):

I recently have to use the line spacing with POI,and my approach was get the paragraph and get the ooxml-schema

```java
XWPFParagraph paragraph;
xml = paragraph->getCTP()->ToString();
```

then the schema will be stored as a String in that xml variable and you have to retrieve the value from this with some string function

```xml
<w:spacing w:lineRule='atLeast' w:line='240' />
```

the w:line is the one you need

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1);
```

It will create a line spacing of 1

Answer (score 0):

```
<w:spacing w:lineRule='atLeast' w:line='240' />
```

Fix

```
XWPFParagraph p
p.setSpacingBetween(1);
CTP ctP = p.getCTP();
CTPPr ctPr = ctP.isSetPPr() ? ctP.getPPr() : ctP.addNewPPr();
CTSpacing spacing = ctPr.isSetSpacing() ? ctPr.getSpacing() :     ctPr.addNewSpacing();
spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(200));
spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.EXACT);
p.getCTP().getPPr().setSpacing(spacing);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).