# Pictures not fully visible in LibreOffice after converting HTML to DOCX using docx4j

Tags: java, hyperlink, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I convert html to docx file with docx4j

I need to get docx document for opening in libreOffice. I create a docx,  but in libreOffice pictures don't visible fully. If I set in properties "attach an image to a symbol" - picture the image becomes fully visible, but the picture moves up. How i can do that pucture will be visible fully and stay on its place. In word pictures show correctly, but I  need libreOffice

I convert html to docx file with docx4j

```
  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
 NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
 wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
 ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
 
 RFonts arialRFonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
 arialRFonts.setAscii(ReportAndTemplateManagementConstants.FONT_FAMILY);
 arialRFonts.setHAnsi(ReportAndTemplateManagementConstants.FONT_FAMILY);
XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping(ReportAndTemplateManagementConstants.FONT_FAMILY, arialRFonts);

 XHTMLImporterImpl xhtmlImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
 
 xhtmlImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
 tempConvertFile =
 File.createTempFile("tempConvertFile", StringPool.PERIOD + ReportAndTemplateManagementWebKeys.DOCX);
 tempFileOutput =
 File.createTempFile("tempFileOutput", StringPool.PERIOD + ReportAndTemplateManagementWebKeys.DOCX);
 
 wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
                     .addAll(xhtmlImporter.convert(content, tempFileOutput.getAbsolutePath()));
 wordMLPackage.save(tempConvertFile);
```

I have img html tag with base64 in src. All my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <p style="text-align: left;   font-size: 12pt;      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;    line-height: 1.15;   " ><strong>СПРАВКА</strong><br />демо<br />25.05.2023<br /><strong>_________________________________________________________________________</strong></p>
   <p  style="text-align: justify;   font-size: 12pt;      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;   text-indent: 35.4pt;   margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;    line-height: 1.15;   " ><ins class="ice-ins ice-cts" data-changedata="" data-cid="2" data-last-change-time="1684999190829" data-time="1684999190829" data-userid="" data-username=""><img src="data:image/png;base64,iV...UVORK5CYII=" /></ins></p>
</html>
```

Image not fully visible:

[image]

UPD with solution:
I compare two xml in file, where picture is visible and in file where picture is not visible. I have found a solution.
Picture is visible: w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="276" w:before="0" w:after="0" />

Picture is not visible: w:spacing w:lineRule="exact" w:line="276" w:before="0" w:after="0" />

so, I set Line rule to paragraphs in such way https://stackoverflow.com/a/27752060/21688996

And It is working! I see my images!

Comment: Any chance of posting a link to the complete html file?

Comment: This is the complete HTML in question

Comment: What is? Only the beginning of the image is given, if you mean the html you posted